# What is the type of map's iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stdmap, std

I am new to C++. I found that to see a variable's type, I can use `typeid().name()` on library `std::typeinfo`.

But when I implement this function on map data structure, I got this output

Type of itr is :

```
St17_Rb_tree_iteratorISt4pairIKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEiEE
```

What is that mean ? Actually I want to know what is type of itr which is the iterator of map in the code section.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>    
using namespace std;
    
int main()
{

    map <string, int> map1;    
    map1.insert({"A",1});

    auto itr = map1.begin();        // Iterator is created by auto

    for (itr; itr != map1.end(); itr++)
    {
        cout<<itr->first<<"  "<<itr->second<<"\n";
    }    
    cout<<"Type of itr is : "<<typeid(itr).name();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, that's its type. In practice, it's pretty much analogous to a `pair<string, int>`. For example, taking `pair<string, int> pr = *itr;` does not cause an error and works as intended.

Comment: The type of the iterator is `std::map<std::string, int>::iterator`.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know what is type of itr which is the iterator of map in the code section?

The type of `map1.begin()` is

```
std::map<std::string, int>::iterator
```

You can test it via

```
#include <type_traits> // std::is_same_v

static_assert(std::is_same_v<
     decltype(map1.begin()), std::map<std::string, int>::iterator>
    , "are not same");
```

i.e. Alternative to `auto` keyword and the above (i.e `std::map<std::string, int>::iterator`), you could use `decltype(map1.begin())` as well.

---

> `St17_Rb_tree_iteratorISt4pairIKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEiEE`
>
> What is that mean ?

It's the name of the type as per compiler implementations. From [`std::type_info::name`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name)

> Returns an **implementation defined null-terminated character string containing the name of the type**. No guarantees are given; in particular, the returned string can be identical for several types and change between invocations of the same program.

Therefore, it could vary compiler-to-compiler, and can not argue this will look the same always.
For instance, have a look into the type of `map1.begin()` in different compiler here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ProxxaxfW